# How to create par2 files multipar command line?

Tags: batch-file, command, line, par

My files are:

```
/aaaaa/11111.rar
/bbbbb/22222.rar
/cccccc/33333.rar
/ddddd/44444.rar
```

I want to create par for files...

```
 /aaaaaa/11111.par2
 /bbbbbb/22222.par2
 /ccccccc/33333.par2
 /dddddd/44444.par2
```

How can I change par name ?

I've tried this code:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM this command script requires Windows 2000/XP
SETLOCAL

SET par2_path="path of par2j.exe"

:GetFilePath
SET target_folder=%1

REM check input path
IF "%~1"=="" GOTO End
IF NOT EXIST "%~1" GOTO NextFile
IF NOT "%~z1"=="0" GOTO NextFile

REM invoke PAR2 client
ECHO create PAR files for %1
%par2_path% c /sm2048 /rr20 /rd1 /rf3 "%~1\%~n1.par2" *

IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO End

:NextFile
SHIFT
GOTO GetFilePath

:End
ENDLOCAL
```

And it works but there is a problem:
par files renamed folder name ...

Comment: It's not clear fro your description or code what exactly the problem is. However `"%~1\%~n1.par2"` is what defines the output file name.

Comment: thanks but i know but how to check %~2 file?

Comment: How do you execute this batch file? Show an the exact command line example.

Comment: i want to drag and drop to cmd file and after that script working... i'm using a lot of script but i didnt find this script ...working but one file drag after that again ...but i want to use script will work all directory files to automaticly...

Comment: What exactly do you plan to drag'n'drop? A file? Several selected files? A directory/folder?

Comment: i want to drag folder and all of folders in folders file will be par2 file to named...this code like but not working                                                           /aaaaa/11111.rar
/bbbbb/22222.rar
/cccccc/33333.rar
/ddddd/44444.rar i want to par files to 1111.par2 2222.par2 but par files named aaaa.par2 bbbb.par2

Answer (score 1):

Asked 1 year ago, but no answer yet.

You have to write more than just `%par2_path% c /sm2048 /rr20 /rd1 /rf3 "%~1\%~n1.par2" *`.
Replace your line with following lines instead:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%d IN ('DIR /AD /B "%1"') DO (
    FOR /F "delims=" %%f IN ('DIR /A-D /B "%1\%%d"') DO (
        %par2_path% c /sm2048 /rr20 /rd1 /rf3 "%1\%%d\%%~nf.par2" *
    )
)
```

---

Let's say you have following structure:

```
Script.bat
dir001
 - aaaaa
    - file.001
    - name.xyz
 - bbbbb
    - test.abc
 - ccccc
    - file.rar
```

The lines above will get all folders in your given (drag&drop) folder and list all files within that folders.
For that files create par2 files in the particular folder.

Drop folder "dir001" on your Script.bat. The output will be something like:

```
Script.bat
dir001
 - aaaaa
    - file.001
    - file.par2
    - name.xyz
    - name.par2
 - bbbbb
    - test.abc
    - test.par2
 - ccccc
    - file.rar
    - file.par2
```

But if you have another file named e.g. "file.txt" in folder "dir001\ccccc", the file won't get any par2 file.
If you like to, change `*%%~nf.par2* to *%%f.par2*` in second `FOR` loop and your par2 files will use full name of file (incl. extension).